# WFS layer with BBOX query loads all data (URL works fine in Browser/FME workbench)

Tags: qgis, wfs, extents, getfeature

I want to pull data from Berlins Geo portal (FIS BROKER).
When I do the query in the browser (Firefox) or through FME Workbench, it returns fine:

Eg.:
https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_wfs_alkis_ortsteile?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=fis:s_wfs_alkis_ortsteile&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:25833&BBOX=390812,%205821130.01,%20392562,%205819077.24

When I add a layer in QGIS, it loads everything…

Could somebody help me with this?

Comment: Did you use the option to restrict to area of interest

Comment: good question... is that an option within qgis?

Comment: Yup, in the data source manager, 'Only request features overlapping the view extent'

Comment: ah yeah... if  you set up the connection that option  is checked by default. thats neat, but then you cant zoom in/out without downloading more data then you need. Have  you been able to bbox wfs urls?

Comment: You could also write a query

Comment: you mean, after everything is downloaded?

Comment: No, as part of the connection

Comment: i dont know what you re hinting at. but the url is basically a wfs query... which works in the browser but not within qgis...

Comment: ah k. the query builder... is this post-download? anyway, i didnt manage to write a proper bbox query. could you give me a tip for the syntax? best, joe.

Answer (score 1):

'Only request features overlapping the view extent' while you load the wfs do the work!

Comment: i d prefer to actually define the request within coordinates... see prev post. it prevents from downloading more if you zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL Query Composer to restrict the extent (using the Build query option when editing the server connection).

[image: Initial Data Source Manager for WFS]

Specifying a  spatial query as the WHERE clause

```
ST_Intersects(geom,ST_MakeEnvelope(390812,5821130,392562,5819077))
```

as below:

[image: SQL Query Composer]

Giving connection as:

[image: Data Source Manager for WFS with SQL query]

The result of the filtered WFS is shown (below) as orange polygons (note funnel icon in Layers panel) on top of the unfiltered WFS showing in purple.

[image: Filtered WFS layer in QGIS]

More information on spatial functions can be found on the GDAL WFS driver page: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/wfs.html